# The functional inequality $f(|x|)+f(|y|) \geq 1/f(|x+y|)$

Tags: functional-inequalities

Please help me to solve the following problem.

Does there exist a nonempty function $f: D_{f} \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $D_{f} \neq \emptyset$ such that
$$
f(|x|)+f(|y|) \geq \frac{1}{f(|x+y|)}
$$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|, |y|, |x+y| \in D_{f}$ ?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you just want an example, or find them all?

Answer (score 0):

What about $D_f = \Bbb{R}$ and 
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb{R} : f(x) = 1
$$

Am I missing something, because this seems too simple.